# Simple Question on the Limits of Integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I was curious as to which variable the limits of integration are here in terms of: $\int_1^3f(x)dm$. That is, are we specifying $\int_{x=1}^{x=3}f(x)dm$ or $\int_{m=1}^{m=3}f(x)dm$? What is the reasoning behind this?

Moreover, what makes it necessary that the integrand, $f(x)$, and the $dm$ component be in terms of the same variable for evaluation? I would think that all elemental quantities, $dm$ or $dx$, specify the same 'width', that is one which is infinitely small.

In advance, thank you for any aid you can provide me.

Answer (score 0):

The Riemann integral is *defined* as a limit, $\int_{x=a}^{x=b}f(x)\,dx = \lim_{\Delta x_k\to 0}\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k^*)\Delta x_k$. So in your case, this means $\int_{m=1}^{m=3}f(x)\,dm$. If $x$ varies as a function of $m$, then the evaluation depends on $x=x(m)$ and on $f$. If not, then the value of the integral is $mf(x)\big|_{m=1}^{m=3}=(3-1)f(x) = 2f(x)$.